# Do comparision after updates hooks of acf-fields?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-value

I have this code:

```
public function init() {
    add_filter('acf/update_value/name=bookitall_fromdate', 
    array($this, 'check_bookingdates' ), 10, 3);

    add_filter('acf/update_value/name=bookitall_todate', 
    array($this, 'check_bookingdates' ), 10, 3);
}

public function check_bookingdates($new_value, $post_id, $field) {

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );           
    if ( $post_type != 'bookitall_bookings' ) 
    {
        return;
    }        
    $old_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['name'], true);
    if ( $old_value == $new_value ) { //No change
        return $new_value; 
    }      

    ...code to check (comparision) fromdate and to date

}
```

I want to compare dates and add dates or remove dates from another tables based on from- and to-date.

The issue is that from- date and to-date can be totally different depending in which order the hooks `acf/update_value/name=bookitall_fromdate` and `acf/update_value/name=bookitall_todate` occurs. I want to do the comparision when both datefields (`bookitall_fromdate` and `bookitall_todate`) has been updated.

**How do I achieve that?**

**This doesn't have to be with acf-fields. The same question applies when using relevant update_meta_key in a filter.**

Answer (score 1):

ACF launches these hooks on the hook `save_post` then you can compare values just before like that :

```
add_action("save_post", function ($post_ID, \WP_Post $post, bool $update) {

    // read old values with get_post_meta($post_id, "bookitall_fromdate", TRUE) ...

    // read new values in $_POST


    // do action if the 2 dates are changed



}, 6, 3); // priority 6 for launching before ACF saving with priority 10
```

Comment: hmm you probably want a later priority not an earlier one

Comment: with a later priority, the old values are probably lost, erased by new values.

Comment: maybe we understood the question differently. My understanding is that he wants to compare them after they were both updated

Comment: @MarkKaplun - You are correct - I want to compare values AFTER update.